# AjaxControlToolkit & RequiredFieldValidator compatibility issue

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I had a ASP.NET webpage with several  text boxes (WebControls) with mandatory data entry. Hence, the text boxes have an associated RequiredFieldValidator & this form was working fine.

Recently, I had to add an additional textbox which accepts date as input. To enforce correct date format, I decided to associate this textbox to the CalendarExtender of the AjaxControlToolkit, so that on clicking the textbox a pop up calendar appears. After successful build of the project, when I navigate to the page an error message “Assembly AjaxControlToolkit does not contain a web resource with name jquery” is returned.

It was also observed that when I deleted all the text boxes & their associated RequiredFieldValidators the Form is working fine. That is when the textbox with CalendarExtender is clicked the Calendar appears without any problem.

It appears that AjaxControlToolkit (ToolkitScriptManager) & RequiredFieldValidator cannot co-exist on a web form.  I am using Visual Studio Professional 2012.

Any suggestions ?. Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you please paste your code what you have done ?

Comment: please update your question with your code..

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the following steps:

Register `Assembly`, `Namespace` and `TagPrefix`

Than put `ScriptManager`

`<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
  </asp:ScriptManager>`

Try the following code for calendar popup:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="myTextBox" runat="server" CssClass="textBoxStyle" Width="282px"> 
 </asp:TextBox>
 <asp:ImageButton ID="myImg" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/myImage.png"/>
 <cc1:CalendarExtender ID="calendarId" runat="server" PopupButtonID="myImg" 
 TargetControlID="myTextBox" Enabled="True">
 </cc1:CalendarExtender>
```